# Define the size of a global array from the command line

Tags: c, pthreads, global-variables, command-line-arguments, semaphore

I am doing an assignment where I need to use pthreads or semaphores to synchronize some processes which access some shared resource.  Since all of our examples in class use a global variable as the shared resource I planned on doing the same thing, but I wanted to base the value of the shared resource on a command line argument.  **I know how to use command line arguments within my main method, but how do I define the size of a global array (the shared resource) based on a command line argument?**

**Update:**

Wallyk's answer seems like it will work, but I'm still fuzzy on some of the finer details.  See the example and comments...

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print_array(void);

int *array;
int count;

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int count = atoi(argv[1]);
    array = malloc(count *sizeof(array[0]));
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++){ /*is there anyway I can get the size of my array without using an additional variable like count?*/
        array[i] = i;
    }
    print_array();
    return 0;
}

void print_array(){
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < count; i++){
        printf("current count is %d\n", array[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're update is really another question, so you should go ahead and select Wallyk's answer.  The closest you can get to not using another variable is to store the `int * array` and `int count` in a struct.  This is really just two variables, but they are tied together in a more obvious way, and you could reuse that struct for other things as well.

Comment: @nategoose it isn't really another question, I just want to be clear on the answer that was given... and I always select an answer eventually :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't do a static dynamic declaration like:

```
int globalarray[n];
```

Where *n* is a variable set at runtime.  This doesn't work because the array is initialized before the program begins running.

A good alternative is to use a pointer to dynamic memory:

```
int *globalarray;

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
...
   int elements = atoi (argv [j]);  // parse out the program argument array size
   globalarray = malloc (elements * sizeof (globalarray[0]));
}
```

Comment: I'm still kind of weak on pointers.  I get what you are doing here, but it brings up a couple of other questions, like how do I populate this global array and how do I find the size of the array if needed (`sizeof(array)/sizeof(int)` does not seem to work).  See my updated question.

Comment: @typoking: you store the number of elements in another variable of type `size_t` and inspect that when you need to know.

Comment: @typoknig:  Remember that arrays and pointers have much in common, so `globalarray[0] =` <somevalue> will work.  Or `int j; for (j = 0;  j < n;  ++j)  globalarray [j] = 0;`  Be sure to make the number of elements also a global so all users of the array can easily determine its size.

Answer (score 3):

A global pointer to a [malloc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc)'d array is one possible solution.
So you malloc the array of needed size depending on your command line argument and make the pointer to the array visible to all your pthreads.